# Trying to use curl to do a GET, value being sent is allows null

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm trying to use curl to do a simple GET with one parameter called redirect_uri. The php file that gets called prints out a empty string for $_GET["redirect_uri"] it shows red= and it seems like nothing is being sent.
code to do the get

```
//Get code from login and display it
$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'http://www.besttechsolutions.biz/projects/facebook/testget.php';

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_GET,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_GETFIELDS,"redirect_uri=my return url");

//execute post
 print "new reply 2 <br>";
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 print $result;
// print "<br> <br>";
// print $fields_string;
 die("hello");
```

the testget.php file

```
<?php
print "red-";
print $_GET["redirect_uri"];


?>
```

Comment: What is CURLOPT_GETFIELDS supposed to be/do ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I usually do get requests, hopefully it will help you:

```
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// Set maximum redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);

// Allow a max of 5 seconds.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

// set url
if( count($params) > 0 ) {
    $query = http_build_query($params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url?$query");
} else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
}

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors and such.
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
if( $output === false || $errno != 0 ) {
    // Do error checking
} else if($info['http_code'] != 200) {
    // Got a non-200 error code.
    // Do more error checking
}

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
```

In this code, the $params could be an array where the key is the name, and the value is the value.

Comment: Thank you,I tried the code, worked when it did a get to my php file, but djd not work when calling face books url. Whet if I paste the url in a browser, face books api returns the correct info, This is hopeless, but thank you for the helop Ted