# PHP - run GET curl, get result

Tags: php, arrays, curl, get

I wanna run a GET curl in php A to get data from php B.

This is an example in php A (I got from here http://support.qualityunit.com/061754-How-to-make-REST-calls-in-PHP)

```
//next example will recieve all messages for specific conversation
$service_url = 'http://localhost/test/getFrom.php?id=1';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}
curl_close($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}
echo 'response ok!';
var_export($decoded->response);
```

And I tried this example as well ([Trying to use curl to do a GET, value being sent is allows null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516863/trying-to-use-curl-to-do-a-get-value-being-sent-is-allows-null))

In php B.
It will get the ID, run some script and will generate an ARRAY.

I want to get this ARRAY from B to A.

B will run only when A request GET from B.

The problem is I don't how the ARRAY can pass from B to A.

Please give some advice THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is expecting back a JSON encoded array. The easiest way to do this is simply JSON encode your array in PHP B and echo it to the page.

Then CURL will be able to read the contents of PHP B, decode and process as required.

```
// PHP B

<?php

  // Check for $_GET params  

  // Get ID 
  $id = $_GET['id'];

  // Do processing, query etc
  ....

  // Format and display array as JSON
  echo(json_encode($result_array));
  die();

?>
```

Also note:

```
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}
```

The code is expecting the array to be formatted in a particular way. So either match your array in PHP B to the same format, or update the code to your needs.